# Query to return all or partial bit values by parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In my database I have an Employees table with a column of type bit called EmployeeType. I have a website that displays various reports for employees based on that.

One report should include `EmployeeType=1`, another `EmployeeType=0` and a third should include all employees regardless of their EmployeeType.

I was hoping to use one stored procedure and just pass an EmployeeType variable. I was thinking that I could do the following and pass either 0, 1, 2 (0 for EmployeeType 1, 1 for EmployeeType 0, and 2 for all EmployeeTypes).

```
 WHERE (Employee.EmployeeType <> @EmployeeType)
```

However, when I pass anything other than 0 or 1 I just get EmployeeType=0 returned.

I'm guessing this is because 2 is an invalid bit type. I'm wondering if there is a way I can do what I'm looking for or if my only options are to change EmployeeType to something such as int, or create two separate stored procedures (one with the WHERE clause as listed above and one without it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a case statement:

```
where Employee.EmployeeType = case @EmployeeType 
                              when 0 then 1 
                              when 1 then 0 
                              else Employee.EmployeeType end
```

Check out this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a9a73/4) for a working example.

As a side note, you said `0 for EmployeeType 1, 1 for EmployeeType 0, and 2 for all EmployeeTypes`  It seems much more intuitive to make this 1 then 1 and 0 then 0.  You could then shorten your statement to be something like:

```
where Employee.EmployeeType = case when @EmployeeType != 2 
                                   then @EmployeeType 
                                   else Employee.EmployeeType end
```

Comment: If you look above you'll see the reason I said 0 for EmployeeType 1 and 1 for EmployeeType 0 is because I wasn't using an = operator but instead <>. Neither of your examples work. Using what you have listed here I get EmployeeType=1 when I pass 2 to the variable, not all employees regardless of type.

Comment: @doby48 could you modify the sql fiddle I provided to duplicate your problem?  It works fine in the fiddle.

Comment: Additionally, I think that you are misusing the bit type here.  What happens when you have a 3rd type of employee?  Usually a reference table is used for this type of problem.  The case statement can still be applicable in most cases as well.

Comment: This is actually a FullTime column, I renamed for the sake of posting here though it probably won't have been a good idea to leave it as-is for clarity. With regards to your solution, it does work. When I went to edit your Fiddle I realized I didn't have the variable set as type int. Once I changed that in my stored procedure everything works as expected. Thanks for your help!